# Find the minimum number of actions to make equal all the elements of the set.

Tags: inequality, optimization, algorithms, maxima-minima, triangle-inequality

> Given a *sorted* set $S = \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$, find the minimum number of actions to make equal all the elements of the set. Action stands for incrementing or decrementing some element of the set by $1$.

I am claiming that this number is $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-m|$ where $m = x_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$. To prove the claim I tried the triangle inequality
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-m| \ge \left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - n\cdot m\right|$$
I know that the equality of the triangle inequality with two variables would occur when $\text{sgn}(x_1)=\text{sgn}(x_2)$, but I don't know how to proceeed with $n$ variables. The claim seems to be correct for special cases.

- **Source:** [Minimum moves to equal array elements II](https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/may-leetcoding-challenge-2021/600/week-3-may-15th-may-21st/3748/). (See the picture)

[image]

Comment: What actions are you allowed to take?

Comment: @RossMillikan Oops, sorry, I will mention it now.

Comment: Please include it in the question, not just as a link, so people do not have to click through.  The link doesn't even contain the information.  Maybe if you log in it does, but people should certainly not have to create an account to answer a question.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry for that I did not know that was invisible. However, that link contained only the problem statement nothing more. The site is leetcode.com.

Comment: Your question specifies the array is sorted, but it does not matter.  Your $x_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ becomes the median of the set.  It is generally true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose a target number $m$, then add to or subtract from each element to get to $m$.  You are correct that the number of actions for a given $m$ is $\sum_{i=1}^m|x_i-m|$.  If you think about changing the target to $m+1$ you will increase the sum by $1$ for all the elements equal to or below $m$ and decrease the sum by $1$ for all the elements greater than $m$.  If over half the elements are above $m$ this is a good thing.  If over half the elements are below $m$ decreasing the target is a good thing.  Leaving the target unchanged is a good thing when it is the median of the set.